# How to set selected value on dropdown list in Angular 5?

Tags: angular

I have the following html select code:

```
<div class="form-group"> 
    <label class="control-label" for="state">State</label>
    <select class="selectpicker" [(ngModel)]="trip.state">
        <option *ngFor="let s of states" [ngValue]="s.state">{{s.state.name}} 
        </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

The component ts file:

```
...
export class Trip1Component implements OnInit {

  @Input() public trip: Trip;
  public countries: Country[] = [];
  public states: State[] = [];
...

loadStates() {
    this.http.get<State[]>(`${this.baseUrl}/States/${this.selectedCountry.code}`, httpOptions).subscribe(
      data => { this.states = data; },
      err => console.error(err),
      () => setTimeout(() => {
        $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
    }, 10)
    );
  }
```

The state entity:

```
export interface State {
    id: number;
    code: string;
    name: string;
  }
```

the states list from console:
[image]
The selected state is not shown in the list, when I display the trip.state.name string on the page I get the correct value! But the drop down list is not
selected. I've tried to use both [ngValue]="s" and [ngValue]="s.state"
The Trip is coming from a parent component using the @input annotation as you can see above.
Any idea how to get this to work?

Comment: Maybe try [value]='s.state.name', and you can set selected also initially by [selected] property. Or you can use id if the problem is with duplicate entries

Comment: I think the state object in trip is different from state array items. Based on id find state object from state array and set that to ngModel variable.

Comment: can you attach the sample json of the states

Comment: what is the properties of Trip input

Comment: the states is coming from http, I added the code for that as well.

Comment: Take a separate variable for selected state,on ajax response set it to first element of array,in ngOnChange event find state object based on id from state array and assign to selected state variable.

Comment: I've added ngOnChanges hook and I found that the states array is not ready at this time, alert(this.states[1]); show "undefined". the trip.state.name is available on ngOnChanges.

Comment: Any idea how to solve this?